# FINDING SPACES with charindex in sql command crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sqlcommand, charindex

I have this code to find a space in the sql command to and return it with the database fields in crystal reports, but the charindex keeps returning zeros.

```
SELECT ALLEGATION, CHARINDEX(ALLEGATION, ' ', 1) AS SPACE
FROM ALLEGATIONS
```

WHY DOES IT KEEP SAYING 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the opposite order:

SELECT ALLEGATION, CHARINDEX(' ', ALLEGATION, 1) AS SPACE
FROM ALLEGATIONS

Comment: Thank you, reversed orders @lan